# Unable to connect to Ec2 using Robo 3T getting Failed to create SSH tunnel to

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am unable to connect ec2 instance from robo 3T while I'm able to connect ec2 server using Ubuntu cmd. I have tried all answer but still facing the issue. for reference i have attached 1) AWS Security group 2) Robo 3T setting

Please help me to resolve this issue

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow remote access from the Mongodb configuration also.

File: `sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf`

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Change to

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

After update this file restart the mongodb server.

Comment: I have did this still getting same error

Comment: I'm even not able to connect ec2 using filezilla

Comment: Are you able to connect the EC2 server using the AWS console or .pem file?

Comment: yes I am able connect using my local Ubuntu cmd